# Viewing the elements of a set by set.toArray()

Tags: java, arrays, set, element, toarray

Is there a way to view the elements of a set by doing something like `set.toArray()[i]` (`i` being an integer)?

Answer (score 0):

## Convert `Set` to array

If you mean to ask if a `Set` can be converted into an array, and then access that array, the answer is “Yes”.

The code you show would return an object of type `Object` rather than the specific type. To get the specific type, use this syntax [shown in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)).

```
String[] stringArray = mySetOfStrings.toArray( new String[0] ) ;
String s = stringArray[ index ] ;  // Where `index` is an `int` variable.
```

Or we could shorten that to:

```
String s = mySetOfStrings.toArray( new String[0] )[ index ] ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JS8wqw).

Beware: If the concrete implementation of the `Set` interface does not promise a certain iteration order, then this code makes no sense. You cannot reasonably ask for the nth element of the array if you do not know the order of the elements.

## `Set` has no order

If you mean to ask if there is a way to get the “nth” element from a `Set`, such as the second or fifth event, the answer is “No”. **A `Set` by definition has no order**. Therefore there is no concept of a second or fifth element.

Some `Set` implementations may not even have consistent, repeatable iteration order. They may iterate in one order one time, and in a different order another time.

## Sorted sets

Java does offer `NavigableSet` and its predecessor, `SortedSet`, both extending the `Set` interface.

Implementations of these interfaces keep the elements in a sorted order. When you iterate such a collection, you will encounter the elements in that sorted order.

Also, an `EnumSet` iterates its elements in the order in which the enum objects are defined.

Notice how in this example code, the month of February was added third in our collection `q1`, but is defined as the second object on the enum [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html). So this `EnumSet` iterates with `FEBRUARY` object after `JANUARY` and before `MARCH`.

```
Set< Month > q1 = EnumSet.of( Month.MARCH , Month.JANUARY , Month.FEBRUARY ) ;
Month m = q1.toArray( new Month[0] )[ 1 ] ;  // Feb.
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JS8wqw).

Comment: I didn't understand the rationale behind DVing this answer. If it is because the question has been marked as a duplicate, the DVer should consider the valuable information put in this answer.